# Pattern matches causes Stackoverflow on long inputs

Tags: java, regex, stack-overflow

I know that there are several thread about this topic, but the found solutions were specific to particular problems and were based on improving the Regex String.

Anyway, I need to process a text input file, where the contained data model a graph structure as adjacent lists. Each line *n* contains a list of vertices adjacent to *n* (noted as integers each), separated by one or more white space characters. I decided to check each line with a regex string before parsing, instead of throwing and catching `NumberFormatExceptions` in case of bad data.

So this is what the code loos like at this point:

```
line = line.trim(); //Remove whitespace in the beginning and in the end of line
if (Pattern.matches("(\\d+\\s*)*", line)){
    //split string and parse vertices
}
```

A line might also be empty, which means that its degree is 0.

It works great for most instances, but fails when a line with ~1000 adjacent vertices is parsed (StackOverflow). I would like to know all ways in which I can solve this issue. I don not want to increase JVM stack size, as the program shall remain portable. Further, I would like to keep using RegEx pattern matching, cause hey, that's what it's for! So hopefully someone has a great idea.

Comment: [Should your title include a "tag"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: If you are just going to check, `"[\\d\\s]"` would be enough.

Comment: Did you want to split the string using regex as well? Just using the Java split function is probably fine for that. Just asking because you are using a group in your regex.

Comment: @acarlon  I'm spliiting the string using line.split("\\s+") later. Is there a proper way?

Comment: That is fine - you were using grouping in your regex which is why I was wondering if you were wanting to split using regex.

Answer (score 5):

Alternate solution has been provided, so I am not going into those. I am going to explain why your pattern causes `StackOverflowError`<sup>1</sup>, and how your regex is also subject to catastrophic backtracking.

<sup><sup>1</sup>`StackOverflowError` occurs if your JVM uses OpenJDK Java Class Library. It may not occur for JVM that uses something else for its class library. However, since Oracle's JRE (which is the most common JRE) uses OpenJDK Java Class Library (Oracle actually maintains OpenJDK), you must take this error into account when writing regex. On a related note, this has been reported as a bug many times in the past - [here is one of them](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6337993), and is still not fixed.</sup>

*Don't accept this answer, since it is not going to give a solution to the problem*

### StackOverflowError

To match a subpattern repeated by quantifier (except possessive quantifier), the `Pattern` class *may* recursively call internal function to match, and therefore use some stack **per iteration**.

It usually will do some analysis on the subpattern to avoid recursive call on simple patterns such as `\w+` or `(?:df)+`, but it is forced to do recursive call for `(?:gd?f)*` or `(?:g|d|f)`. Note how there is no choice point for the former case, but there is choice point for the latter case. Common patterns that have choice points are quantifiers (possessive excluded) or alternative `|`.

If the input string is long enough, so that the subpattern repeats for thousands of times, you will get `StackOverflowError` for your pattern, since it contains choice point.

Possessive quantifiers don't have choice point, since it disallows backtracking. The engine has no need to backtrack, so it doesn't need to call recursively to store information on stack.

### Catastrophic backtracking

Your pattern subjects to catastrophic backtracking, since you can find a string that can be matched by your regex in different number of iterations. In a **matching input**, usually one or two branches are explored, but all those branches are explored when the input string is a **failing input**.

As an example, let us use a simple input, `1234` with the regex `(\\d+\\s*)*`. It can be matched in several different ways by the regex above.

```
1/2/3/4    (4 iterations)
1/2/34     (3 iterations)
12/34      (2 iterations)
1234       (1 iteration)
1/23/4     (3 iterations)
```

On a failing input such as `1234 5678 x`, the engine will backtrack all the ways you split up the number. The trace below show the first few attempts in order tried by the engine:

```
1234 /5678 /x
1234 /567/8 /x
1234 /56/78 /x
1234 /56/7/8 /x
1234 /5/678 /x
1234 /5/67/8 /x
1234 /5/6/78 /x
1234 /5/6/7/8 /x

123/4 /5678 /x
123/4 /567/8 /x
123/4 /56/78 /x
123/4 /56/7/8 /x
123/4 /5/678 /x
...
```

If the input consists of a long number, and many such numbers, you are going to go into a backtracking hell.

Comment: Interesting... What happens if you do `Pattern.matches("((\\d+\\s*){1,32})*", line)`?

Comment: So it's keeping all these in case it needs to backtrack. So what happens if you use possessive quantifiers? Something like this: `"^(\\d++\\s*+)*++$"`. Or probably `"^(\\d+\\s*)*++$"` would be enough.

Comment: @DavidKnipe: A subpattern repeated with possessive quantifier will still backtrack when it is matching the subpattern. After the subpattern is matched (iteration complete), it will discard the info from the subpattern, since it won't be needed. I think the engine is probably using a loop for possessive quantifier, since it only need to loop until it fails to match the subpattern.

Comment: I assume the subpattern match is small enough that we don't need to worry about its stack size.

Comment: @DavidKnipe: There is nothing that guarantee about the subpattern's stack usage. You can cause stack overflow with a pattern such as `((df?g)*)*+`. Note that the outer most is possessive, but the inner subpattern is a normal greedy quantifier.

Comment: I'm not surprised if `((df?g)*)*+` causes a stack overflow, because the inner `*` is the one that runs lots of times. I suspect that `(df?g)*+` would be fine.

Comment: @DavidKnipe: Right, it is fine, since the stack usage is very low.

Comment: this answer should go to the wiki, or at least to the official javadoc

Comment: @Leo: It is totally *inappropriate* for `StackOverflowError` to go into Javadoc, since this behavior is *not* a behavior that an implementation of `Pattern` class should have. This is more of a flaw in the Oracle's implementation of `Pattern` class. Other JVM implementation may provide their own implementation that doesn't have this problem. As for catastrophic backtracking, I think it should be documented (since it is a problem for most backtracking engine).

Comment: @nhahtdh I strongly disagree. Javadoc is not JSR. It's not a standard, it's the documentation of the implementation, so it's the appropriate place to document possible problems caused by a specific implementation. Of course, if it's related to Oracle's JVM implementation, then I am talking about Oracle JVM javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using the regex to extract the individual numbers, so you can get away with just checking to make sure the line contains just digits and whitespace. Your regex can be as simple as `"[\\d\\s]*"`.

Comment: +1, I came to similar conclusion - doesn't he need to check beginning and end of line though?

Comment: Edit: It needs to be [\\d\\s]* in order to accept empty process empty strings as well, right?

Comment: @user3184683: Sorry, I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use

```
^[\\d\\s]+$
```

Basically, this will match for sequences of white space and digit making sure that there are not other characters between the beginning of the line and the end. Your original parses my test string in 3000+ steps, this takes 3 steps.

This has these results:

```
123123  123123  123123  123123 - OK
1 - OK
123g 12r3123 123 - NOT OK
```

Comment: Thanks, same solution as Gebe provided. Same here: It should be [\\d\\s]* in order to not ignore empty lines (as empty lines are valid and represent a vertice with degree 0).